# Java yield() a thread with synchronized block to a higher Priority thread also with a synchronized block.

Tags: java, multithreading

From what I understand, yield() on a thread does not release the lock for that thread. So if there are two Threads and both of them have synchronized block in the thread pool, A with lower priority and B with higher priority. If Thread A is running and yield() is called in A, thread B now will run by scheduler. Because currently, thread A is still holding the lock, so thread B can not go into the critical block? From my understanding, this will cause a deadlock?

Please let me know do I miss something?

Thanks very much:)

Comment: There's no reason to call yield() at all. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: The `.yield()` method is an artifact of those times where multiprocessing was in its infancy, both OS wise and, in the case of Java, language wise. This method only exists for backward compatible reasons, but really, you should not rely on its behaviour in code written with recent JDKs. The [documentation of this method itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield--) clearly mentions that it is a _hint_ to the (OS) scheduler; the latter is free to completely ignore this hint, therefore read: behaviour unspecified. Use other primitives instead. Java has plenty.

Comment: There's no deadlock, because there is only one lock. The higher-priority thread blocks trying to obtain the lock, and the lower-priority thread remains eligible for execution.

Comment: @EJP So the process will never finish in this case ? Can you give me some hints about how to handle this situation normally ?

Comment: That's exactly the opposite of what I said. (1) *There is no deadlock,* and (2) *the lower-priority thread remains eligible for execution.* So, eventually, it executes, releases the lock, and the higher-priority thread can now proceed.

Comment: @EJP I am sorry about that, I kind of understand why is that. Is that because when _lower-priority_ thread yield(), the scheduler **may** schedule the _higher-priority_ to execute, but the _higher-priority_ thread can not execute because it can not enter critical area so the scheduler execute the _lower-priority_ thread ?

Comment: Of course it can. It has to schedule something, if there is anything that's runnable.

Comment: Almost as little reason to mess with priorities as with yield. Avoid both of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some confusion here.

1. There is no deadlock, because there is only one lock. You need at least two locks for a deadlock.
2. `yield()` does essentially nothing. See the Javadoc.
3. At any time, possibly including when you call `yield()`, the higher-priority thread will block trying to obtain the lock. So it is no longer eligible for execution. So the scheduler will have to schedule something else that is runnable.
4. Meanwhile the lower-priority thread remains runnable (i.e. eligible for execution), so it will get scheduled sooner or later, so it continues to execute. Sooner or later it will release its lock, which will allow the higher-priority thread to acquire it and continue its execution.

Answer (score 2):

Yield won't deadlock because it's only a transient *suggestion* to the scheduler, not a permanent state, as better explained in the answer by EJP.

If you goal is to yield to higher priority threads within a critical section, you can't accomplish what you want with `yield()`, since it doesn't interact with locks (i.e., it doesn't know or care that the current thread holds a lock).

You could, however, use methods such as `Object.wait()`, which is able to release the currently held lock. It has a specific usage pattern, however (i.e., you `wait()` in order to later be notified) - which may not fit your needs. If it doesn't Java 8 offers a rich variety of synchronization primitives (separate from the implicit monitor associated with each `Object`) - one of which is likely to fit your needs.

Comment: How do you know what he wants when he hasn't stated it? He is asking about the specific behaviour of these two threads, not how to implement a specific requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that a live thread with a higher scheduling priority *exists* does not prevent a thread with a lower priority from running.  The thread has to exist, and it has to be live, and it has to be *runnable*.

A thread that is blocked waiting for a mutex is not runnable.  A thread that is waiting for a condition variable is not runnable.  A thread that is waiting for anything other than a CPU to run on, is not runnable.

Low priority threads are allowed to run whenever there is a CPU that is not wanted by a higher priority thread.  If they weren't, then "priority" would be meaningless.

---

That being said, unless you are running your program on a special "real-time" implementation of Java, the "priorities" that you set for your threads are not their true scheduling priorities anyway:  They are just hints to the scheduler that one thread should be allowed to use more CPU time than another if it wants.